# Changing Bundle ID causes app to break

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to change my Bundle ID from the default one to the one I created in Apple's Developer Center. But when I change the Bundle ID in the plist, then delete the app on my phone and try to run it from XCode, I get the following error:

```
Could not launch "MyApp"
No such file or directory (then it lists a path to the app's DerivedData folder)
```

Am I supposed to do anything special when I change the app's Bundle ID?

Comment: Did you try to clean the project? Delete the whole `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory.

Comment: Weird, I deleted the data specific to my app from Derived Data before, and that didn't fix it, but when I deleted the whole folder, that made it work. Thanks so much, been tearing my hair out for an hour on this. Feel free to add your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning the project. I prefer to simply delete the whole `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder, because Xcode sometimes messes up and doesn't clean properly.

Consider writing a simple bash script for that. In `~/.bash_profile` (you might have to create this file first) add this:

```
clean(){
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
echo "Removed all derived data."
}
```

Save and run `source ~/.bash_profile` (or restart Terminal).

Now you can simply type `clean` into any terminal window and it will clean all your projects.